# How to obtain node inventory for rundeck from chef

Tags: chef-infra, rundeck

The workflow automation tool [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) sources structured text files to create its inventory of nodes. But if you use chef as your source of truth of your server/node inventory, its undesirable to have to create these flat files just for rundeck to reference. How can rundeck obtain this information dynamically from a chef server?

Answer (score 2):

chef-rundeck is a sinatra app (ruby) that interfaces with a chef server and exposes the node inventory data through a REST API in XML format.

https://github.com/oswaldlabs/chef-rundeck

I run it under [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for easy management of the process, management of log files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try updating the attributes of the nodes in chef via ohai.

Then from rundeck you can simply have a script to pull the attributes to rundeck where the chef tags can also be reciprocated to rundeck node tags