# Automating Rundeck in a CD platform- adding nodes to rundeck

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-delivery, rundeck

I am exploring Rundeck for my Continuous Delivery platform. The challenge I could foresee here is automating the rundeck itself - **adding the nodes to the Rundeck whenever a new node/vm get created**.

I thought of creating the vm with the the public keys of my rundeck server and adding the vm details into the resources file [~/rundeck/projects/../resources.xml]. But its an inefficient approach as I have to manage the resources.xml file by removing the entries each time a vm is deleted. I am primary depending on chef for infrastructure provisioning, getting the node inventory from the chef seems like a viable solution but it adds more overhead and delays in the workflow.

It would be great if I could get some simple/clean suggestions for solving the problem.

Comment: The rundeck cookbook (https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/rundeck) contains thr chef rundeck gem that will automatically retrieve the Rundeck node list from chef server. I don't understand your comments about "overhead and delay". If chef is your system of record for your servers retrieve the resource list from there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain node inventory for rundeck from chef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008330/how-to-obtain-node-inventory-for-rundeck-from-chef)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you could download and use chef-rundeck gem from the below link.
https://github.com/oswaldlabs/chef-rundeck

But if you need audit information on the nodes like who added a node or who deleted a node or when the changes in node info occurred, I would suggest maintaining a node info file in SVN or Git and use the URL source option.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in the Poise Rundeck cookbook via the [rundeck_node_source_file resource](https://github.com/poise/rundeck#rundeck_node_source_file).